# How to define a shortcut for OS X terminal using Shift-PageUp?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

Using the system settings, I tried to re-map the keyboard shortcut for previous and next page from Cmd-Pageup/Dn to Shift-Pageup/Dn. However, the system settings dialog for shortcuts does not seem to recognize the PageUp key or the combination of Shift-PageUp/Dn. Can I fix this?
Running on El Capitan, if that matters.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that is not an existing shortcut? You can't create conflicting keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be a task for [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), because you cannot natively create shortcuts using the Page Up/Down/Home/End Keys